# To what extend can pre-training and training affect the results of a prediction model?

Tags: forecasting, train

If we pre-train a model forecasting COVID-19 with data of SARS, which had a different transmission pattern, will our model be weakened?

If we train the same model with data of (for instance) the USA, will the model work well for another region and country with a different situation?

Comment: Some interesting discussion on this thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61753/statistics-expected-values-and-philosophy/61760#61760

Comment: The fact you have even asked these questions suggests you know the answers.  Are they any more than rhetorical?

Comment: @whuber I am not a statistician nor a programmer.  I am not sure if doing these two things is a methodological error or if it can be acceptable. It seems to me that it is an error.